# Which user group can use the 'tap' net device?

Tags: networking, permissions, kvm

I use the 'tap' net device with KVM to get my vm connect to the Internet. But I have to be root, or use 'sudo', which is inconvenient. I think I can put my user account into some group so I can access the net device without root privilege. I tried the **netdev** group, but does not work. My account is already in the **kvm** group.

What else should I do? Or is there any way to allow me using KVM freely without permission issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The group is whoever has read and write permissions to `/dev/net/tun`. The default setup varies from distribution to distribution. The ownership and permissions of devices is set by [udev](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev).

Create a file `/etc/udev/rules.d/zzz_net_tun.rules` containing

```
KERNEL=="tun", GROUP="netdev", MODE="0660", OPTIONS+="static_node=net/tun"
```

This will make the device accessible by all users in the `netdev` group. The setting takes effect when the device is created, so if it already exists, do `chgrp netdev /dev/net/tun; chmod 660 /dev/net/tun`.

(adapted from the [Gentoo Wiki](http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/QEmu#Using_TUN.2FTAP_interface_as_a_normal_user) wiki)

Comment: I tried the last two commands on my Ubuntu 15.04 box but user space applications still can't seem to access it: "qemu-system-arm: -net tap,ifname=tap0: could not configure /dev/net/tun (tap0): Operation not permitted". I verified that the group is set to `netdev` and permissions set to `0660`. (And I'm in the `netdev` group.)

Comment: @NathanOsman What's the output of `groups` and `ls -l  /dev/net/tun`? Run `strace -o qemu.strace qemu-system-arm net tap,ifname=tap0 …` and look at the part of the trace where it tries to open `/dev/net/tun`. What's going on exactly? If you can't figure it out, ask a new question with all this information.

Comment: I finally decided to just ask a new question anyway: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/243382/1049 I'll still run `strace` and see if I can't get to the bottom of this.

Comment: hi! I followed this answer (I'm in the group netdev, I added the udev rule, opened a new shell to make the group effect) but still getting the message "could not open /dev/net/tun: Permission denied". ubuntu 16.04. Any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: @ChanKim Opening a shell is not enough. You need to log out and back in. Check with `id` or `groups` that you are in the group as expected.

Comment: `id` and `groups` show that I'm in group netdev. I  tried changing the udev rule file so that tun device belongs to me, or event changing the /dev/net/tun permission to 777 (including /dev/net directory). It's the same for me. Strange..

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are part of the KVM group also. The recommendantion is to make every virtualization things (network configuration, firmware access, qemu configuration) available for the kvm group.