# Making /dev/net/tun available to qemu?

Tags: qemu, network-interface, tap

I have created a tap device (`tap0`) which I would like to provide as a network interface to qemu. I created the device with the following command and attached it to a network bridge I set up:

```
tunctl -t tap0
ifconfig tap0 up
brctl addif virbr0 tap0
```

I then ran the commands suggested in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/18283/1049):

```
chgrp netdev /dev/net/tun
chmod 660 /dev/net/tun
```

Both commands completed successfully and I confirmed that they took effect:

```
nathan@nathan-desktop:~$ stat /dev/net/tun
  File: ‘/dev/net/tun’
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   character special file
Device: 6h/6d   Inode: 1224        Links: 1     Device type: a,c8
Access: (0660/crw-rw----)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (  108/  netdev)
Access: 2015-11-16 10:16:35.127338320 -0800
Modify: 2015-11-16 10:16:35.127338320 -0800
Change: 2015-11-16 10:37:18.338948110 -0800
 Birth: -
```

I also confirmed that I am in the `netdev` group:

```
nathan@nathan-desktop:~$ groups
[...] netdev [...]
```

**However,** when I attempted to start a qemu virtual machine with the interface, I encountered the following error:

```
nathan@nathan-desktop:~$ qemu-system-arm [...] -net tap,ifname=tap0
qemu-system-arm: -net tap,ifname=tap0: could not configure /dev/net/tun (tap0): Operation not permitted
qemu-system-arm: -net tap,ifname=tap0: Device 'tap' could not be initialized
```

#### strace

The relevant output from `strace` is presented below:

```
open("/dev/net/tun", O_RDWR)            = 7
ioctl(7, TUNGETFEATURES, 0x7ffcc532ab2c) = 0
ioctl(7, TUNSETVNETHDRSZ, 0x7ffcc532ab28) = -1 EBADFD (File descriptor in bad state)
ioctl(7, TUNSETIFF, 0x7ffcc532ab30)     = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
write(2, "qemu-system-arm:", 16qemu-system-arm:)        = 16
write(2, " -net", 5 -net)                    = 5
write(2, " tap,ifname=tap0", 16 tap,ifname=tap0)        = 16
write(2, ": ", 2: )                       = 2
write(2, "could not configure /dev/net/tun"..., 64could not configure /dev/net/tun (tap0): Operation not permitted) = 64
write(2, "\n", 1
)                       = 1
close(7)                                = 0
write(2, "qemu-system-arm:", 16qemu-system-arm:)        = 16
write(2, " -net", 5 -net)                    = 5
write(2, " tap,ifname=tap0", 16 tap,ifname=tap0)        = 16
write(2, ": ", 2: )                       = 2
write(2, "Device 'tap' could not be initia"..., 37Device 'tap' could not be initialized) = 37
write(2, "\n", 1
)
```

Comment: Ah, the error is “operation not permitted”, not “access denied”. This means that the problem is not access to the device file, but some operation that requires additional privileges (here that would be an ioctl call that requires root or some capability that other parameter combinations don't require). So please do run `strace` and see exactly what ioctl is failing.

Comment: @Gilles `strace` output added.

Comment: @NathanOsman any suggestions on what to do if `tunctl` is not available on the system (ArchLinux 2018 here) ? I'm trying to achieve the same thing you tried, but I'm failing at the step of `tunctl`.

Comment: @Nathan Osman Have you solved this issue?

Answer (score 8):

qemu is going to try to run some default scripts that will fail if you are not root.  Here is a working command-line option for when you have appropriate access to the appropriate tap device:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 ... \
    -net nic,model=virtio -net tap,ifname=tap0,script=no,downscript=no
```

The `script=no,downscript=no` is important to avoid that failure.

You also have to make sure you have access to the other end of the tap device (not just the control device `/dev/net/tun`).  Not sure about `tunctl`, but with iproute2, you have to say `ip tuntap add dev tap0 mode tap group netdev` (or `user`, etc.).

Comment: Note that `-net` is now a legacy option for qemu.

Answer (score 5):

Create the tap interface with the user you are working.

```
sudo tunctl -p -t tap0 -u <user>
```

Then try running the Qemu.

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify the netdev group in your initial tunctl call:

```
tunctl -t tap0 -g netdev
```

[I also found out that, for some reason, I had to give execute permission (770) on the /dev/net directory. This may not be related.]

Comment: I have permissions 755 on `/dev/net`. I wouldn't mess with that.